# Is it possible to have Windows Installer register a 64-bit shell extension which is wrapped in a 32-bit Component?

Tags: com, registry, windows-installer

I have an InstallShield Basic MSI project which builds both 32-bit and 64-bit installers using Release Flags mechanism to build the different packages with the correct Template Summary, etc. One of my Components is an explorer.exe shell extension, so in order for this to work it needs to be registered in the 64-bit node in the registry when installed on windows 64-bit, NOT in the Wow6432Node. However, because this is a 32-bit Component to Windows Installer it will get registered as such and go down the Wow6432Node. I am told by InstallShield that this is native Windows Installer behavior and there is really no way around this other than Custom Actions (which I have already resorted to).

Do I have to resort to running regasm? This is what I currently do however I would rather not use Custom Actions for something like this. Also, it appears that other products have the same pattern: a 64-bit shell extension, however installed down program files (x86). I see TFS Power Tools and WinZip doing this for example. For these products, I do NOT see regasm.exe running so I assume they have some other mechanism for this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but can't you do this with a 32-bit install containing only the 32-bit extension and the 64-bit install that contains both the 32-bit and 64-bit extensions each of which go to WOW and native registries? That means you can't have a common source unless the IS build lets you omit some components in the common build depending on the architecture.

Comment: The problem is the 64-bit installer is targeting OFFICE 64-bit - that is what differentiates it from the 32-bit install. The application being installed is not 100% pure 64-bit anyway, and it cannot because it installs third party 32-bit-only DLLs.

Comment: A 64-bit install can install 32 and 64-bit components. Your 64-bit setup can have a 32-bit component with 32-bit Dll and a different 64-bit component with the 64-bit version of the Dll and install them both to their respective different registry and disk locations. 32-bit systems get the 32-bit install, 64-bit clients get the 64-biy install. The only thing forbidden is a 32-bit setup cannot contain a 64-bit component, so if that's your problem then yes that's the way MSI works. Otherwise I am obviously still missing something, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set ***msidbComponentAttributesDisableRegistryReflection*** ([Component table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) attribute for that component?

Comment: Yes. This attribute does not help me because my component is 32-bit. Basically, if the component attributes < 256 (mine is '0' for this one) then it will install to wow6432node